# How to move up and down a multi selected checkbox list item

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, html-lists

How to move up and down a multi selected check box list item,

```
 <div id="ListElement">
    <ul><li><label><input type="checkbox"/>ProfileSender/Author</label></li>                    
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Profile Recipient</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"/>Profile Subject/Title</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Document Review Doc ID</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Profile Date</label></li>
    </ul><span><a class="upArrow ser-arrow-up" title="Move Up" onclick="moveUpDown(true)"></a> <a class="downArrow ser-arrow-down" onclick="moveUpDown(false)" title="Move Down"></a></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move up and down"? Do you want to move items with mouse?

Comment: no click on up and down button

Comment: Well you dont have up/down buttons in your snippet and how do you want to select an item to move? with the checkbox?

Comment: i have write this code after ul end<span><a onclick="moveUp()" title="Move Up" class="upArrow"></a> <a title="Move Down" onclick="moveDown()" class="downArrow"></a></span>

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
function moveUpDown(isUp) {  
    var selectedItems = $('#ListElement ul li.is-active').map(function() {
        return this;//.parent().text();
    }).get();

    if(selectedItems.length==0){
        var msg = isUp==true? "Please select items to be moved up." :"Please select items to be moved down.";   
        alert (msg);
        return
    }

    if(isUp){       
        var first = 0;
        $.each(selectedItems, function(index, listItem){          
            var oldIndex = $( "#ListElement ul li" ).index( listItem );
               if(oldIndex != first) var newIndex = oldIndex - 1;
            $('#ListElement ul > li:eq('+newIndex+')').before(listItem);
        });
    }else{
         var last =  $('#ListElement ul > li').size()-1;
        //console.log(last);
        $.each(selectedItems.reverse(), function(index, listItem){
            var oldIndex = $( "#ListElement ul li" ).index( listItem );
                if(oldIndex != last) var newIndex = oldIndex + 1;
            $('#ListElement ul > li:eq('+newIndex+')').after(listItem);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#entry-examples)

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

jsfiddle demo here :

http://jsfiddle.net/87mCR/

try dragging one li with mouse

Comment: Thanks for ans but actually i want to move up and down all selected item when i click up and down button